# Bulletin Board System with tagging, email notification

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, web-applications

I am looking for nice BBS system, Bulletin Board System, Discussion Board, or nice in-company communication platform.

There are lots of people, about 30 people, joining in our project.
We would like to share idea among us on that platform.
We can post questions and concerns related with the project, and we
would like to respond each other.

Here is my list of functionality I want:

- Tagging Thread

  e.g) Announcement, Finance, Legal, Idea. One thread
  can have multiple Tags.
- members can set on/off to receive email when new comments are
  posted. They can set on/off on each Tag.

  e.g) one member on to receive email related with "Announcement", but
  off to receive "Finance".
- Thread owner can change threads' tag any time.
- Thread can have several type of post.

  - Thread can be "vote" thread. Everyone can vote their opinion.
  - Thread can be "action plan" thread.  In this thread, "who" will
    "what" remains in the thread.
    By viewing all "action plan" thread, all action plans needed in
    the company is visualized.

Comment: I think I can find you a forum application that can do everything accept for the the feature *Thread can have several type of post. *. If you wouldn't mind a lack of that feature, then I might be able to help you.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a project management system more than a forum setup. Have you looked for something under that umbrella that may fill your needs?

Comment: If you are developing software I would suggest Trac http://trac.edgewall.org/ so you can communicate with developers post tickets and manage the code with Subversion. Though that's for software development... You didn't specify the project you're working on. If you need a simple forum go with phpBB

Answer (score 0):

I would give http://www.teamworkpm.net/ a go, it is project management software but I think it will tick off all your needs.